# How to make a route being allowed for use only one time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

After Sign Up I redirect the users to a route that they can chose if they want to add a photo for their account, but I want this route to be able for access only after they sign up, so they can add a photo later in the "Edit Account" but I want this route to not be allowed even if they type it after like /users/chosephoto. But it's not working because the route is still allowed

So I want this route to be accessible only one time(after they sign up) so later on even if they are signed in and they try to enter /users/chosephoto I want them to be redirected to the root_path

Controller

```
before_action :visited_chosephoto, only: [:add_photo]
...


def chose_photo
   @user = current_user
end

def add_photo
   @user = current_user
   @user.update_attribute(:photo,params[:user][:photo])
   @user.chosephoto_visited = true
   @user.save
   redirect_to root_path
end
```

User model

```
def chosephoto_visited=(chosephoto_visited)
   @chosephoto_visited = chosephoto_visited
end

def chosephoto_visited
   @chosephoto_visited
end
```

the method

```
def visited_chosephoto
   redirect_to root_path if current_user.chosephoto_visited
end
```

route

```
 get 'users/chosephoto' => "users#chose_photo", as: "chosephoto"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define in your controller:

```
def can_access_choose_photo?
  return false unless current_user.present?
  # return true  if request.get?
  return false if current_user.chosephoto_visited
  return true
end

def choose_photo
  if can_access_choose_photo?
    current_user.update_attributes(chosephoto_visited: true)
    # other actions
  else
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

**Note 1** You don't need `before_action` here. Checking is used only by a single action.

**Note 2** You should also add `chosephoto_visited` column to your `User` model. Otherwise, it won't work as intended.

Comment: it's not if the user is not signed in...after the user signs up I redirect them to the /users/chosephoto and they can chose a photo...but later on even if they are signed in I want them to not be able to go to this route..I want to make this route usable only one time(after they sign up) because they can add a photo on the "Edit profile" later

Answer (score 0):

```
before_action :visited_chosephoto, only: [:add_photo, :chose_photo]
```

Adding the second option for the filter will run the method also for the chose_photo action

Comment: what is the controller code for the chose_photo action?

Comment: I added it on the post

Comment: Is the chosephoto_visited boolean actually saving to the user record in the database when you go to add_photo? Can you run this action and post the console log output?

Answer (score 0):

You can check in before filter if the HTTP referrer for that page is user signup, if it is you allow the user to visit **chosephoto** page otherwise you can redirect user to root url.

```
if !URI(request.referer).path == '/signup' || !URI(request.referer).path == nil
  redirect_to root_path
end
```